# Split tensor according to value

Tags: tensorflow

How do I generate N different sparse tensors for N unique values for a given tensor?
For example, if I have:

```
tensor = [[1,3,4,5],[1,2,3,2],[3,3,4,5],[2,2,1,4]]
```

I want the results to be:

```
ch1 = [[1,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0]]
ch2 = [[0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,1],[0,0,0,0],[1,1,0,0]]
ch3 = [[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]
...
```

How can I do this in tensorflow? Assume I have a NHWC-formatted tensor.

Answer (score 1):

Got it. we can use `tf.one_hot()`